# For getting a more accurate location result in Android which one to use FusedLocationApi vs FusedLocationProviderClient?

Tags: android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I was going to develop an android application that deals with users' current location. Then there I noticed two type of examples on the web. One using `FusedLocationApi` and another one using `FusedLocationProviderClient`. The first one is very much easier to use than the second one.

I don't understand the difference between them and which one is better to use.

Someone, please help.

Thank you in advance buddy.

Answer (score 0):

FusedLocationProviderApi is deprecated, Now u can go with FusedLocationProviderClient to get more accurate location.

Google provides the sample in github

[https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location](http://Play%20location%20sample)